# indexofobject returning nil

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to build a walk-through of the app using scenes built up from a storyboard.

So I populate my array of viewControllers called pages:

```
@interface PVCPagesViewController () {
    NSMutableArray *pages;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;


@end
```

in viewDidLoad():

```
self.pages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIViewController *page1 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page1"];

UIViewController *page2 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page2"];

UIViewController *page3 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page3"];

UIViewController *page4 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"page4"];

self.pages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:page1, page2, page3, page4, nil];
```

But when Im about to load another view controller from the array in viewControllerAfterViewController():

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSInteger index = [self.pages indexOfObject:viewController];

    index++;

    return [self.pages objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

I am getting a valid viewController and I see it in the array, but when I try objectAtIndex, it returns nil?

```
(lldb) po self.pages
<__NSArrayM 0x170243cc0>(
<UIViewController: 0x13cd05370>,
<UIViewController: 0x13cd06030>,
<UIViewController: 0x13ce00000>,
<UIViewController: 0x13ce11b60>
)

(lldb) po viewController
<UIViewController: 0x13cd05370>
(lldb) po [self.pages indexOfObject:viewController];
<nil>
(lldb)
```

What gives?   Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

`indexOfObject:` doesn't return an object, which is what the `po` command (`print --object-description`) expects; it returns an `NSUInteger`. Use the plain `print` command:

```
(lldb) p (NSUInteger)[self.pages indexOfObject:viewController];
0
```

When you use `po`, the index 0 is interpreted as an object pointer. The 0 pointer is `nil`, so that's what is printed. If it had been any other value, the debugger wouldn't have known what to do with it, because it almost certainly wouldn't have been a valid object pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Just try like this below:-

```
   (lldb) p (NSInteger) [self.pages 
   indexOfObject:viewController];
```